# Duplicate domain names with hyphens being the only difference

Tags: seo, google, domains

I have a website which is not being picked up by Google. The only thing I can see is that the domain is exactly the same as another domain, but the words are split by hyphens.

The sites are:

- www.keyword1keyword2keyword3keyword4.co.uk, and
- www.keyword1-keyword2-keyword3-keyword4.co.uk

Is this the reason I fail to get any ranking?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'not getting picked up?' Your site is being indexed, about 12 pages pop up for site:my-holiday-home-insurance.co.uk. Do you mean your ranking isn't high enough?

Comment: Creating a bunch of low quality sites is not as efficient or effective as creating a single high quality site. If those two sites have essentially the same content (or provide the same service), then it's better to just combine the two and redirect one domain to the other.

Answer (score 2):

The site is indexed so you're not blacklisted or anything along those lines. Supposedly domains with multiple hyphens do not get an exact match bonus for keywords in them so that may be hurting your rankings.